# How To Animate CSS Animated Hamburger Icon On MouseOver

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've got an animated  CSS Hamburger icon at http://elijahmanor.com/css-animated-hamburger-icon/ and I wanna  need to use it but I want to use it via hover to view set ex(x) and when not hover set it to default style that 3 lines. But I cannot do that even I used hover function.

```js
document.querySelector("#nav-toggle")
  .addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
```

```css
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

#nav-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using mouseover function.

```js
document.querySelector("#nav-toggle")
  .addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
```

```css
#nav-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

#nav-toggle {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}

#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span,
#nav-toggle span:before,
#nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}

#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before,
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}

#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

The hover event is called `mouseover`.

> The events name are the classic [HTML DOM Events](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp), just without the
>   *on* prefix. For example, use `mouseover` instead of [`onmouseover`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseover.asp).

```js
document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" )
  .addEventListener( "mouseover", function() {
    this.classList.toggle( "active" );
  });
```

```css
#nav-toggle { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; }

#nav-toggle { cursor: pointer; padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px; }
#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px; 
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use `mouseover` instead of `hover` at your script.

```
document.querySelector("#nav-toggle")
  .addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `mouseover` event.

```js
document.querySelector( "#nav-toggle" )
  .addEventListener( "mouseover", function() {
    this.classList.toggle( "active" );
  });
```

```css
#nav-toggle { position: absolute; left: 50%; top: 50%; }

#nav-toggle { cursor: pointer; padding: 10px 35px 16px 0px; }
#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 1px;
  height: 5px;
  width: 35px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  content: '';
}
#nav-toggle span:before {
  top: -10px; 
}
#nav-toggle span:after {
  bottom: -10px;
}

#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<a id="nav-toggle" href="#"><span></span></a>
```