# How to Use Fontawesome Bars For Animated Hamburger Icon

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

Previously I read the blog of Elijah Manor about [**CSS Animated Hamburger Icon**](http://elijahmanor.com/css-animated-hamburger-icon/) and it's recommended to use **[Fontawesome bars](http://fontawesome.io/icon/bars/)** for this. Fortunately I always use [Fontawesome](http://fontawesome.io) but unfortunately it's difficault for me to use fa-bars for animated hamburger icon instead I use right now the CSS hamburger icon that hoverable that I ask [**previously**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864619/how-to-animate-css-animated-hamburger-icon-on-mouseover). How could I use fa-bars as a animated hamburger icon?

Comment: Hi TechGirl. Can u paste here a JSFiddle link?
In the Elijah Manor blog the animations are in CSS and JS. On click add a class .active with css proprierties.

Comment: Don't use the fa-bars to create an animated icon. As explained in [the blog post you link to](http://elijahmanor.com/css-animated-hamburger-icon/), the animation requires the 3 bars to be separate elements (created using CSS). The single static fa-bars icon doesn't give you the possibility to animate its separate parts.

Comment: I have no codes using fontawesome bars right now instead I use the this codes located at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43864619/how-to-animate-css-animated-hamburger-icon-on-mouseover.

Comment: Sir @phillchill  please read carefully the blog and it's recommended to use fontawesome bars but not necessary. But I eager to use it. I'm looking for a way to use it.

Comment: > "You could use Font Awesome or an image to represent the hamburger, but those aren’t necessary. Instead, you can create a version of the hamburger only using CSS and the following markup."

That's talking about non-animated icon. For the animated version you need to CSS and markup detailed in the post.

http://elijahmanor.com/css-animated-hamburger-icon/

Answer (score 1):

I used HTML, CSS and Jquery. Kinda messy though.

```js
$(".hamb").click(function(){
  $(".menu").toggleClass("active");
  $(".spanf ").toggleClass("span1 ");
  $(".spans ").toggleClass("span2 ");
  $(".spant ").toggleClass("span3 ");
});
```

```css
.hamb {
  background: #f0f0f0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.hamb span i {
  width: 50px;
  height: 10px;
  background: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 25%;
}

.span1 .span2 .span3 i {
  position: absolute;
}

.hamb .spanf:nth-child(1) i {
  top: 20%;
}

.hamb .spans:nth-child(2) i {
  top: 40%;
}

.hamb .spant:nth-child(3) i {
  top: 60%;
}

.span1:nth-child(1) i {
  top: 40% !important;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.span2:nth-child(2) i {
  left: 130px;
}

.span3:nth-child(3) i {
  top: 40% !important;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.menu {
  position: relative;
  left: -150px;
  top: -17px;
  transition: left 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
.menu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
}
.menu ul li {
  font-size: 18pt;
  background: #f0f0f0;
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
.menu ul li:hover {
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.active {
  left: -40px;
  top: -17px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hamb"><span class="spanf"><i></i></span><span class="spans"><i></i></span><span class="spant"><i></i></span></div>
<div class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
    <li>Menu 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

kindly use following css

```
#nav-toggle span, #nav-toggle span:before, #nav-toggle span:after {
  transition: all 500ms ease-in-out;
}
#nav-toggle.active span {
  background-color: transparent;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before, #nav-toggle.active span:after {
  top: 0;
}
#nav-toggle.active span:before {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
#nav-toggle.active span:after {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

and run it with following jquery

```
 $("#nav-toggle" ).click(function(){
this.classList.toggle( "active" );

});
```